# Why, in a folder in gnome, is the common gesture - right-click ... create new file of <type> - not readily available?

Tags: linux, user-interface, desktop, gnome

Why does gnome not support the gesture  ?

Is it a design choice?

UI efforts have discovered this behavior that humans like and have come to expect as a matter of a basic of the human/computer interface.

The proprietary UIs/OSes have adopted it.
Why not gnome?
It's Common Knowledge/Best Practice....

Also, gnome won't present, after a default install, steps to take to recover how to do in a free *nix UI what is common in the non-libre Win and Mac UIs.

This is ... "help!!!" -- I can't do x in gnome that I used to do in Mac and Win. Where is the help (or the implementation)?

PS ... I also just found out that I can't drag a url from the browser to a gnome folder to create a www link and can't either drag a link from the gnome file browser to a gnome folder to create a link. Is this an integration problem - that the parts of the system won't/can't communicate w/each other?

---

This is a "meta" question about libre software adoption of UI best practices and so, suggestions of how to refine it/recategorize it are welcome.

The problem is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must create template files first.

https://tipsonubuntu.com/2019/10/31/enable-new-document-right-click-menu-ubuntu-19-10/